# Fallo en la relacion al crear un registro

Tags: php, sql

Me salta el fallo en el que apunta a una llave foránea (categoria_tr) al querer crear un registro, la he revisado varias veces y hecho las pruebas y no veo la lógica ya que es una relación simple.
El fallo que tira es:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`hs_base`.`trabajadores`, CONSTRAINT `trabajadores_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`categoria_tr`) REFERENCES `categorias` (`id_categoria`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) in
```

Os paso detalle de todo a ver si veis algo.

este es el Select donde paso la llave para crear registro

```html
<div class="form-group">
                                                <label for="">Categoria</label>
                                                <select name="categoria_tr" id="" class="form-control">
                                                <option value="0">--Seleccione categoria--</option>
                                                    <?php
                                                    foreach ($categorias_datos as $categorias_dato) { ?>
                                                        <option value="<?php echo $categorias_dato['id_categoria']; ?>"><?php echo $categorias_dato['nombre_cat']; ?> </option>
                                                    </option>
                                                    <?php
                                                    }
                                                    ?>
                                                </select>

                                            </div>
```

Ahora os paso el controlador de crear el registro en el que entiendo esta bien recogida:

```php
$codigo_tr = $_POST['codigo_tr'];
$dni_tr = $_POST['dni_tr'];
$nombre_tr = $_POST['nombre_tr'];
$sexo_tr = $_POST['sexo_tr'];
$fechanac_tr = $_POST['fechanac_tr'];
$categoria_tr = $_POST['categoria_tr'];
$inicio_tr = $_POST['inicio_tr'];
$centro_tr = $_POST['centro_tr'];
$activo_tr = 1;
$formacionpdt_tr = $_POST['formacionpdt_tr'];
$anotaciones_tr = $_POST['anotaciones_tr'];


$sentencia = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO trabajadores (codigo_tr, dni_tr, nombre_tr, sexo_tr, fechanac_tr, formacionpdt_tr, categoria_tr, inicio_tr, centro_tr, anotaciones_tr, activo_tr, fyh_creacion, fyh_actualizacion) 
VALUES(:codigo_tr, :dni_tr, :nombre_tr, :fechanac_tr, :sexo_tr, :categoria_tr, :inicio_tr, :formacionpdt_tr, :centro_tr, :anotaciones_tr, :activo_tr, :fyh_creacion, :fyh_actualizacion)");

$sentencia->bindParam('codigo_tr', $codigo_tr);    
$sentencia->bindParam('dni_tr', $dni_tr);
$sentencia->bindParam('nombre_tr', $nombre_tr);
$sentencia->bindParam('sexo_tr', $sexo_tr);
$sentencia->bindParam('fechanac_tr', $fechanac_tr);
$sentencia->bindParam('categoria_tr', $categoria_tr);
$sentencia->bindParam('formacionpdt_tr', $formacionpdt_tr);
$sentencia->bindParam('anotaciones_tr', $anotaciones_tr);
$sentencia->bindParam('inicio_tr', $inicio_tr);
$sentencia->bindParam('centro_tr', $centro_tr);
$sentencia->bindParam('activo_tr', $activo_tr);
$sentencia->bindParam('fyh_creacion', $fechahora);
$sentencia->bindParam('fyh_actualizacion', $fechahora);
```

Tambien os paso el controlador donde se genera el select:

````php
<?php
$sql_categorias = "SELECT cat.id_categoria as id_categoria, cat.nombre_cat as nombre_cat, cat.descripcion_cat as descripcion_cat, dpo.nombre_dpo as nombre_dpo FROM `categorias` as cat
INNER JOIN departamentos as dpo WHERE cat.departamento_cat = dpo.id_departamento";
$query_categorias = $pdo->prepare($sql_categorias);
$query_categorias->execute();
$categorias_datos = $query_categorias->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)```
````

y por ultimo una imagen de lo que es la relación en phpmyadmin:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: categoria_tr es un id de categoria valido?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error dice claramente que el valor que estás pasando al campo `categoria_tr` no existe en la tabla de referencia, llamada `categoria` en el campo `id`.

Lo primero que uno pensaría revisar es que el controlador esté recibiendo el valor correcto en la variable `$categoria_tr`:

```php
$categoria_tr = $_POST['categoria_tr'];
```

Suponiendo que esa parte ya se había hecho, lo siguiente sería revisar
tu sentencia insert:

```php
$sentencia = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO trabajadores (codigo_tr, dni_tr, nombre_tr, sexo_tr, fechanac_tr, formacionpdt_tr, categoria_tr, inicio_tr, centro_tr, anotaciones_tr, activo_tr, fyh_creacion, fyh_actualizacion) 
VALUES(:codigo_tr, :dni_tr, :nombre_tr, :fechanac_tr, :sexo_tr, :categoria_tr, :inicio_tr, :formacionpdt_tr, :centro_tr, :anotaciones_tr, :activo_tr, :fyh_creacion, :fyh_actualizacion)");
```

Haciendo esto, veo que los campos de la cláusula `into` no están en el mismo orden que los parámetros de la cláusula `values`, probablemente porque has ido editando poco a poco el programa y no has sido lo suficientemente cuidadosa de mantener este orden. Tomando solo el SQL voy a poner los campos uno por  línea y los voy a numerar, creo que eso dejará claro el problema:

```sql
INSERT INTO trabajadores (
  codigo_tr            /*  1 */
, dni_tr               /*  2 */
, nombre_tr            /*  3 */
, sexo_tr              /*  4 */
, fechanac_tr          /*  5 */
, formacionpdt_tr      /*  6 */
, categoria_tr         /*  7 */
, inicio_tr            /*  8 */
, centro_tr            /*  9 */
, anotaciones_tr       /* 10 */
, activo_tr            /* 11 */
, fyh_creacion         /* 12 */
, fyh_actualizacion    /* 13 */
) 
VALUES(
  :codigo_tr           /*  1 */
, :dni_tr              /*  2 */
, :nombre_tr           /*  3 */
, :fechanac_tr         /*  4 */
, :sexo_tr             /*  5 */
, :categoria_tr        /*  6 */
, :inicio_tr           /*  7 */
, :formacionpdt_tr     /*  8 */
, :centro_tr           /*  9 */
, :anotaciones_tr      /* 10 */
, :activo_tr           /* 11 */
, :fyh_creacion        /* 12 */
, :fyh_actualizacion   /* 13 */
)
```

Si observas, en la lista de campos de la cláusula `into`, el campo `categoria_tr`  está en la posición 7, mientras en la cláusula `values` en la posición 7 está el parámetro `inicio_tr`, por lo que es el valor que le pasas a este parámetro el que se va a insertar en el campo `categoria_tr` de la tabla.

No está de más recordar que, en SQL, la cláusula `insert` toma los valores de la cláusula `values` según su posición, por lo que deben estar en el orden correspondiente.

#### Solución

La solución, en tu caso, es poner los parámetros en el mismo orden en que están los campos en la cláusula `into` de la sentencia `insert`.

Moviendo de posición los parámetros, por ejemplo, debiera quedar algo como:

```sql
INSERT INTO trabajadores (
  codigo_tr            /*  1 */
, dni_tr               /*  2 */
, nombre_tr            /*  3 */
, sexo_tr              /*  4 */
, fechanac_tr          /*  5 */
, formacionpdt_tr      /*  6 */
, categoria_tr         /*  7 */
, inicio_tr            /*  8 */
, centro_tr            /*  9 */
, anotaciones_tr       /* 10 */
, activo_tr            /* 11 */
, fyh_creacion         /* 12 */
, fyh_actualizacion    /* 13 */
) 
VALUES(
  :codigo_tr           /*  1 */
, :dni_tr              /*  2 */
, :nombre_tr           /*  3 */
, :sexo_tr             /*  4 */
, :fechanac_tr         /*  5 */
, :formacionpdt_tr     /*  6 */
, :categoria_tr        /*  7 */
, :inicio_tr           /*  8 */
, :centro_tr           /*  9 */
, :anotaciones_tr      /* 10 */
, :activo_tr           /* 11 */
, :fyh_creacion        /* 12 */
, :fyh_actualizacion   /* 13 */
)
```

#### Justificación

Usualmente votaría por cerrar esta pregunta como error tipográfico, pero he decidido escribir la respuesta esperando que sea de ayuda a novatos en SQL que puedan estar sufriendo de este mismo problema.

Comment: gracias @jachguate, si esta desordenado, voy a revisarlo segun me comentas y os mantengo al dia.

Comment: Todo perfecto es según comentas faltaba orden en el controlador, lección aprendida.